# Pandas Boxplot Highlight Specific Values in DF

Tags: pandas, highlight, boxplot

I have a df called "YMp" and I have made a boxplot for the data with the dates 1991 - 2019 but I need to show the current year (2020) values as colored points or values with a legend showing the year 2020 over-plotted on the boxplot.

The data looks like this -

```
month    01    02    03    04    05    06    07    08    09    10    11    12
year                                                                         
1991   -4.9  12.2 -11.1 -18.0 -27.5   1.7   7.4  22.7  38.3   4.2  -0.9   5.3
1992  -10.9 -17.1  -7.7  14.8  14.8  -9.6  17.0  24.7  32.3   0.3 -21.6  15.3
1993   -1.8  -2.3  -3.8   0.4  -4.8  -7.7  11.7  26.3  17.1   2.6   4.4   2.4
1994    2.6   2.5  -6.2  -3.2   2.2  -3.0  13.8   3.9  30.4 -25.7  -1.8  -2.2
1995   -8.6  -3.3 -18.4 -14.0 -19.3  13.2   9.8 -23.2  16.0 -15.2   0.6  -8.5
1996   -5.5 -10.4  -0.3   7.2  13.0   3.6   5.2   1.4 -10.3  -2.9  15.4  -0.6
1997  -11.1   8.9  -1.1 -12.7   3.0  -4.0  27.1  32.6  -4.5 -15.5  -5.5 -20.9
1998  -22.0 -16.6   3.2   0.7  15.4  16.0  18.5   2.7 -32.3  16.3  -5.4  12.9
1999   -1.0   0.3  -8.5   9.9   7.4  -2.1  10.9  -5.5  18.5  17.4  17.5  11.1
2000    5.4  12.9 -24.8  15.7  -9.3  20.7  18.2  23.2  16.6  26.8 -17.7  17.3
2001   -3.9  14.5  -4.7  18.6   5.6  22.4  -3.3  18.2   5.3  31.2   6.0  -4.0
2002   -9.0  19.5  12.5  24.5  27.6  -9.3   3.7  13.7 -32.7 -19.5   0.7  -6.1
2003   23.6 -11.7 -16.5  -2.1   6.5 -13.7   0.4   8.0 -13.7 -16.1   7.3  13.1
2004    6.6   4.7  36.8  12.8  29.5   6.4 -12.2  -0.6  -7.7 -15.2  -1.1  12.7
2005    6.3   1.1 -14.6   9.4  -7.5   6.1  -9.2  -1.3  36.1  -4.9  10.8 -11.7
2006    7.3   8.3   1.7  11.8 -14.7  33.3   9.1  -0.0   3.0   1.4  -2.8   8.8
2007    5.4   0.2   7.2  -3.9   6.6  -8.3 -28.2  -7.6   3.3  -7.4  25.0  -7.3
2008    5.0  -5.6   7.6  -0.4  -1.2  13.9 -11.3 -29.7  16.7  43.1   2.4   3.5
2009   -2.2  17.1   9.8   8.9  -9.2 -14.4   6.1  21.7  -0.2 -26.7  -9.1 -18.2
2010   -2.6 -12.1   0.8 -16.5   4.1   3.9 -21.5  -3.3 -18.9  22.8  -6.5  -5.3
2011  -12.4  -3.8   1.2 -14.9  -2.0   6.8 -12.6 -16.9   8.3  10.7  -0.7   4.6
2012    0.5  -3.0  -1.0  -6.5   7.5 -17.9  -4.3 -26.3  -2.6   3.0  12.3 -15.3
2013   -1.7 -15.1  18.8  -8.3   7.5  -4.5 -19.3   0.9 -33.9 -10.6  -0.4   4.4
2014    7.2 -20.0  -8.4   2.0  10.1 -20.2   7.8 -14.9 -11.4  -6.9  -0.3   6.4
2015   18.4   6.2  10.5 -16.5 -11.9   7.0  -7.3  -6.7 -20.8 -13.9  -3.3 -14.8
2016  -11.3  28.5  -9.2  -4.2  -9.7   1.0  -5.1 -18.9  -3.3  19.1  -1.1  10.1
2017   -8.6  -8.1  21.2   4.5 -21.2 -28.5  -6.8 -30.8 -19.7  13.3   7.2   9.9
2018   26.9   3.1  -7.1  -3.4  -8.7 -15.5  12.8   3.9 -16.4  -7.9 -25.7  -9.2
2019    2.1 -17.3  10.2   1.0 -13.5  -3.4 -14.0 -20.7  -1.5 -28.4  -5.4 -13.9
```

The current year 2020 data looks like this -

```
2020    0.3   6.2   2.0 -17.9  -0.4   6.0 -24.5   2.5 -12.1   4.6   NaN   NaN
```

My boxplot looks like this without the 2020 data plotted or highlighted below. Thank you for helping with ideas about doing this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try catching the axis instance and plot again:

```
ax = df.boxplot()
ax.scatter(np.arange(df.shape[1])+1, df.loc[2000], color='r')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Typo: `df.loc[2020]`.